# Triggering 'selected' on dynamically filled select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a  elements that I dynamically fill based on the values of another select element using javascript + jQuery. I'm having issue with the 'paper' select detecting any options being selected. Since they're being added dynamically, will I have to detect any changes and force the 'selected' attribute manually?

Here's the markup:

```
<select name="pricing" id="pricing">
    <option value="Standard White">Standard White</option>
    <option value="Classic Paper">Classic Paper</option>
    <option value="Designer Paper">Designer Paper</option>
    <option value="Premium Paper">Premium Paper</option>
</select>
<select name="paper" id="paper"></select>
```

And the javascript function that runs when '#pricing' changes:

```
function paperPopulate() {
    var type = $('#pricing').val();
    var standardPaper = ['Standard White', 'Smelly White'];
    var classicPaper  = ['Ivory Gloss', 'Silly Gloss'];
    var designerPaper = ['White Smooth', 'White Garbage'];
    var premiumPaper  = ['Glacier Faucet', 'Desert Stink'];
    var data = '';
    var papers = {Standard:standardPaper, Classic:classicPaper, Designer:designerPaper, Premium:premiumPaper};
    $.each(papers, function(term, papers) {
        if (type.indexOf(term) !== -1) {
          for (var i in papers) data += '<option value="'+ papers[i] +'">'+ papers[i] +'</option>';
        }
    });

    $('#paper').html(data);
}
```

Because the attribute never adds, the server-side code I run to store the form data never detects what the 'paper' select has selected.

edit: So after double checking in javascript, I see that the page itself understands that an option is selected, however the attributes are not present. The major issue here is that the server-side code (VB.NET) can't see the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't select any option in a select element then by default first option gets selected and it is posted along with the form data when you submit the form.

If you want to set any option as selected then use `val()` jQuery method to select it passing the value of the option to select.

```
$('#paper').val('valueToSelect');
```

Comment: What event do I use the .val() handler during? Do I run it at a #paper.change(), or would I use .live() to listen for any changes?

Comment: Yes, I know I can set it anywhere in the code. I'm asking when I would apply the value. Should I listen for a change on the select? On an option.click()? I'm assuming there are a variety of ways to handle this, but I don't know which is best.

Comment: The best place is after you have updated the options items of this select element. Now you know when you update the options of this element and do it there.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much better way to do this in jQuery. Assuming that `#paper` is your select list, something like this should work:

```
$("#paper").empty();

$.each(papers, function(term, papers) {
    if (type.indexOf(term) !== -1) {
        for (var i in papers) {
            //you can select the option here if needed
            $("#paper").append(
                $("<option>", { value : papers[i], text : papers[i] })
            );
        }              
    }
});

//you can also set the selected value here
$("#paper").val("...");
```

Comment: That helps, though if I append I would need to clear out the select every time it changed. That said, would this fix the select not detecting changes and applying the selected attribute?

Comment: I don't want to just set a value manually in javascript, I want the select to behave like a normal select would. Hit the dropdown, click an option, have it have the 'selected' attribute once clicked, then have the server detect it.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, but this is kind of the "accepted" way to add options to a select using jQuery. I'm revising my answer to show you how to clear the options too.